# Plot with "Replace All"

Tags: plotting, functions, replacement

let's say we have a quadratic equation `ax^2 + 5x + 2 = 0` and I want one of the roots to go into function `y = Sin[x^2]` and after that I want plot of `f[a] = y` with `a` ranging from `[1,3]`.

What I've done so far:

`roots = Solve[a*x^2 + 5*x + 2 == 0, x];`

`y = Sin[x^2] ./ x -> roots[[1]]` - so I solve the equation and apply one root to the `y` function. What I'm struggling with is how do I draw the plot of `f[a]=y` with a range of `a`.

`Plot[f[a]==y,{a,1,3}]` is not working.

How do I do it?

Comment: This should work: `Plot[Evaluate[Sin[x^2] /. roots], {a, 1, 3}]`, it plots both roots as a function of `a`.

Comment: It worked, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Plot[Evaluate[Sin[x^2] /. roots[[1]]], {a, 1, 3}]
```

[image]